# Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br> String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: php, android, json, httprequest

I know that this question has been answered so many times. I have tried different links but I am unable to solve this problem.

**Java code**:

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Username",u));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Email",e));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password", p));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Confirmpassword", cp));
JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_logindetails, "POST", params);
```

**PHP code**:

```
$response = array(); 
// check for required fields 
if (isset($_POST['Username']) || isset($_POST['Email'])|| isset($_POST['Password']) ||isset($_POST['Confirmpassword']) ) { 

  $Username = $_POST['Username']; 
  $Email = $_POST['Email']; 
  $Password = $_POST['Password']; 
  $Confirmpassword = $_POST['Confirmpassword'];

  // include db connect class 
  require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php'; 
  // connecting to db 
  db = new DB_CONNECT(); 
  // mysql inserting a new row 
  $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO login(UserName, email,password,confirmpassword VALUES('$Username','$Email','$Password','$Confirmpassword')"); 
  // check if row inserted or not 

  if ($result) { 
    // successfully inserted into database 
    $response["success"] = 1; 
    $response["message"] = "Company successfully added."; 
    // echoing JSON response 
    echo json_encode($response); 
  } else { 
    // failed to insert row 
    $response["success"] = 0; 
    $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred."; 
    // echoing JSON response 
    echo json_encode($response); 
  }
} else { 
  // required field is missing 
  $response["success"] = 0; 
  $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing"; 
  // echoing JSON response 
  echo json_encode($response); 
} 
?>
```

Comment: I think your server response is html String instead of JSON String.

Comment: yes that is true but i do not know how to correct it. Can you provide me the code ?

Comment: validate response using jsonlint. your php code seems okay. maaybe some database connection error which is the cause of html output.

Comment: Didn't help me much.... Is there anyone who could help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

BasicNameValuePair("Username",u) its not right 
BasicNameValuePir("Username")

Comment: This should be comment and u still don't understand problem.

Comment: @HareshChhelana with reputation 1 user can't post comment. so he tried to help posting answer.

Comment: @HareshChhelana its oky. :)